# MySQL Swap Values(not between fields)

Tags: mysql

I'd like to ask help swapping values within a single field. Table goes something like this:

TABLE

```
FIELD1   FIELD2
 X       HELLO
 Y       TEST
```

Basically i'd like to swap X and Y values(X becomes TEST and Y Becomes HELLO). Already know how to swap or move values between fields but i'm having difficulty with this. Sorry for lame table illustration.

Comment: why you want to swap values between rows? in order to give a good answer we need to know more about the context

Comment: @fthiella, why does not mather, there can be many reasons. I need to do the same, because someone in my onlineshop put products in the wrong slider and I need to swap it out.

Answer (score 0):

this will does your job successfully

```
    UPDATE
rules AS rule1
JOIN rules AS rule2 ON
( rule1.rule_id = 1 AND rule2.rule_id = 4 )
SET
rule1.priority = rule2.priority,
rule2.priority = rule1.priority
;
```

Comment: here table name is 'rules' and column name is 'priority' . Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: this link is for your reference    http://www.microshell.com/database/sql/swap-values-in-2-rows-sql/